# Posso ter uma tabela de configurações sem primary key?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, hsqldb

Em banco de dados, essa tabela será para armazenamento de informações e terá apenas uma linha, sendo que poderá haver updates e inicializará nula e ao decorrer do programa será adicionado. É possível ter uma tabela sem primary key para essa função? E como realizar o select? `SELECT dado1, dado2, dado3 FROM table`? Agradeço desde já.

Comment: O problema nem é como fazer o `select` e sim como fazer o `update`. Se bem que, pra todo efeito, um update sem where já serviria.

Comment: Sim, ai não utilizaria where. Vou por id que me incomodo menos hehe, abraços e valeu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É bem complicado responder sem conhecer o contexto que você está trabalhando. Geralmente criamos um arquivo de configurações (.ini, .properties ou .conf) e gravamos em disco, para programa locais. Na WEB criamos alguma variável de sessão. Caso realmente você deseje gravar em banco de dados, minha sugestão é criar uma tabela com 3 campos (ID, Chave, Valor). Assim você poderá guardar tantas informações diferentes quanto precisar. ID = chave primaria da tabela; Chave = indica o significado do campo valor; Valor = a informação que você deseja guardar.

Comment: Sim, realmente em algumas partes eu utilizo o .properties em outras um .txt normal, mas é que preciso implementar com DAO, esses dados serão exibidos em campos do software permitindo somente a primeira inserção e a quantas edições o usuário querer. Esse software é um instrumento de avaliação em uma cadeira de CDC. Valeu.

Answer (score 0):

Sim, você pode ter essa tabela de configurações sem uma chave primária.
Ao buscar, você irá adicionar um LIMIT 1 para trazer apenas uma linha no resultado.

Embora eu acredite que a inclusão da chave primária seja mais adequada, e ela trará mais benefícios do que problemas. Pois caso em algum momento você precise ter mais de uma linha de configuração, você poderá usar o ID para fazer UPDATE ou DELETE. Então eu sugiro adicionar a coluna de chave primária.

Comment: Além disto eu faria uma trigger de before insert e delete nesta tabela , ser ela for acionada geraria um erro para impedir a operação, isto garantiria um só registro na tabela. Toda operação permitida seria UPDATE  e com apenas um registro não precisaria de uma chave primária.

Comment: @Motta o banco que uso é meio bosta, digamos, não tem suporte para nada, e a sintaxe é diferente dos db que trabalhei/tenho conhecimento. E fora que não há ferramenta case para ele, sou obrigado a fazer tudo na mão, isso atrasa ainda mais, mesmo assim obrigado pela dica.

Comment: @Diego Keller vou precisar somente de uma linha mesmo, é para armazenar as informações da "empresa", obrigado pela dica, acho que vou utilizar mesmo um id, só me surgiu essa dúvida enquanto modelava.